# Hiding Events without a Description in FullCalendar + Google Calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, hide, google-calendar-api, information-hiding

I am using FullCalendar 2.3.1 and a Google Calendar feed.

I know you can set portions of `eventRender` to show/hide specific portions of the event that aren't shown at default (such as adding in the Event Description on an event). I was wondering if it were possible to use a callback to function as "if there is no `event.description`, then do not show the event."

This is the piece of code I used for adding in `event.location` and `event.description` to the event blocks when on `agendaDay` view:

```js
eventRender: function(event, element, view) { 
             if (view.name === "agendaDay"){
              element.find('.fc-title').append(
   "<br/><b>Location: </b>" + event.location,
               "<br/><b>Details: </b>" + event.description);
               }
         }
```

And it works great, so is there a modification of this kind of function that can be done to hide events that don't currently have anything in the `event.description` field?

All help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/):

`The function can also return false to completely cancel the rendering of the event.`

So you can do something like this

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (!event.description) return false;
}
```

Comment: You are a miracle worker! Thank you!!
Now I just need to figure out how to get tooltips to work, but I know there are lots of posts about that.